# symfony actions are super slow on localhost

Tags: symfony1

I've setup MAMP on OSX 10.6 and the exact same symfony code takes over 6 seconds to run on localhost and 200ms on my server. My web debug bar says the time hit comes from processing the action. I've tried it the production mode on localhost and the speed boost was minor, time went to 3 seconds instead of 6. Still ridiculously slow compared to my server.

The strange thing is that non symfony php code runs correctly and fast.

Comment: does your server have APC installed? what are the specs of your server and your laptop/desktop? It's normal to have that increase of speed on a server... Oh and how fast is dev mode on the server?

Comment: yes, APC is enabled for the localhost as well as the server. The time for the dev mode on the server is about 200ms. My laptop is a newer model macbook pro. The specs don't explain the huge time difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Xdebug profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to find out precisely which part of symfony is so slow.

Comment: I found, ([via this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252504/symfony2-slow-page-loads)) that Xdebug was precisely the cause!